# Gallium & Electrolysis

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

Preface this with I'm a chemistry newb. Ive finished chem I and II and did extremely well, but I think that means I know just enough to get myself in trouble....Also, sorry if this is a little long. I've been wanting to do this for awhile now and I finally have the time, but I really only have the time to try it once or twice and get it right. I definitely don't have the time to start from scratch and make a new sample.

I've been working with gallium over the summer after becoming fascinated with it over the last couple of semesters. I have two samples of what I think is gallium chloride, but over the last few days of reading I'm not so sure.

The 1st sample was prepared from the little tube that the gallium was shipped in that had a thin film of gallium I wasn't able to remove. That took about 7 days and I didn't use any heat or stirring, but I did use concentrated HCl. 7.5mL concentrated HCl and based on the mass of the tube before and after removing the gallium, it had 0.71g of gallium. After it was fully dissolved, I set it on a hotplate in a hood and evaporated off all the liquid and was left with some small white crystals. I filled it up with water, the evaporated it again, the added about 30 mL of water and put it in a little bottle. Today I ran it through a filter because it had some white solid in it. It clogged a glass and gave off a little gas so I set up another buchner with a paper filter and was able to pull it all through. This sample is currently clear.

The 2nd sample was prepared by dissolving 2.33g of gallium in 60mL of 6M HCl. I could have used concentrated HCl but I grabbed 6M off the shelf. Took about 5 days. I let it sit overnight but while I was on campus I had it on a hotplate with light heat and moderate stirring. After it was completely dissolved, I let it cool and poured it into a storage container as is. It ran through the glass buchner fine. This solution is currently yellow.

After filtering each, the pH on sample 1 was about 2, and the pH on sample 2 was about 1. I did the math on the 2nd sample and I think I have about 3.61g excess HCl in solution, I didn't do the math on the 1st sample but I was surprised at the pH considering I evaporated off the solution until crystals formed, twice.

What I'm attempting to do with all of this is put the gallium chloride solution into a small dish and run electrolysis to pull out the gallium metal. The only info I've really been able to find on electrolysis of gallium has been a couple of youtube videos. In both videos they mention that electrolysis needs to be performed under basic or highly basic conditions. After they make their gallium chloride, they add sodium hydroxide to make sodium gallium hydroxide. I guess I could have just dissolved the gallium in a concentrated solution of sodium hydroxide, but the one example I saw of this seemed like it would take way to long.

So, a couple of questions:

1. Why can't I/shouldn't I just put the gallium chloride I currently have into a beaker and run electrolysis?

I did the math on it and it looks like gallium metal should be able to be pulled out of this solution, but I believe chlorine gas would form at the anode. The videos I saw didn't look like they were done in a lab or under a hood so I was thinking maybe this was why they made the sodium gallium hydroxide, the the chloride ions are still in solution so this explanation doesn't really make sense. I don't really understand why electrolysis needs to be performed under acidic or basic conditions. We only touched on electrolysis in chem II, mostly just how to tell what's going on at the anode or cathode.

2. Can I use graphite for both electrodes?
3. I understand why the pH is close to 1 for solution 2 that had so much excess HCl, but I don't understand why solution 2 is so acidic. After evaporating off the solution twice, I dissolved the crystals in about 100mL of water. I guess I just thought the pH would a little higher. I had an organic professor help me today with the filtration and he didn't really have an explanation for this either, just thought it was interesting after the two evaporations.
4. I'm assuming solution 2 is yellow because I didn't do anything with it after the gallium dissolved. Is that correct?
5. If I need to or should add sodium hydroxide to make the sodium gallium hydroxide, can I add sodium hydroxide to each solution as is, or should I evaporate off solution 2 until it's clear? I understand this process is very exothermic and I saw it boil over in one video. I was going to basically add 1 pellet of sodium hydroxide at a time from our stock bottles and let the solution cool back to room temp and do this until it's finished... how do I tell if it's finished? Can I/should I do this in an ice bath or chill the solution first?
6. Ok last one.... IF I did all my math correctly, I should be able to run solution 2 as is at 2.7amps for 1 hour to pull out the 2.33g of gallium. I don't think that would change if I use the sodium gallium hydroxide.

The two examples I've seen of this are done with heat. One mentioned it was being performed at 40*C, so they got liquid metal. I wanted to try it once this way and then I'd like to try it in an ice bath and see if I can get gallium crystals. As mentioned earlier, we got a very brief into to electrolysis in our class. How does the math change for time and amps between a run with heated vs cooled solution?

Ok that was a lot. Thank you in advance!

Comment: **TL: DR** $  $...

Comment: Gallium does *not* readily crystallize. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium "Ga nanoparticles can be kept in the liquid state below 90 K." Can you electrolyze it at liquid N2 temp?

Comment: The school has liquid N2, I'm pretty sure one of my professors would let me try it. They've been pretty helpful with this essentially pointless project so far. Not sure they'll be as accommodating when the fall semester starts and they have to start teaching again.  What about the electrolysis set up at room temp forming molten gallium?

Answer (score 0):

To preface, I can only answer the electrochemistry questions.

The pH at which you do electrodeposition is dependent on a range of factors, in general the first thing to do is to check a Pourbaix diagram (from: Chung, Yonghwa & Lee, Chi-Woo. (2013). Electrochemistry of Gallium. Journal of Electrochemical Science and Technology. 4. 1-18. 10.33961/JECST.2013.4.1.1.)

[image: Pourbaix diagram of Ga from Chung, Yonghwa & Lee, Chi-Woo. (2013). Electrochemistry of Gallium. Journal of Electrochemical Science and Technology. 4. 1-18. 10.33961/JECST.2013.4.1.1.]

As you can see if you do not want to form a passivating film of Gallium oxide you need to deposit from either acidic or alkaline solutions in aqueous electrolytes. Next you see the deposition voltage is below the dotted line, these lines signify the electrochemical limits of water. You will partially be forming hydrogen gas during deposition, depending on your substrate and the catalytic activity of Gallium it can be that in acidic or alkaline conditions you're more likely to form more hydrogen gas (or even form hydrides) which limits the current efficiency (how much is going to Gallium deposition vs to some other processes). Sometimes depositing from different pHs makes you get a smoother finish or other results that are preferred, now for your educational exercise this is not super relevant.

Next, on the question of graphite. You can use a graphite cathode, but I would advise against a graphite anode. Because, as you've mentioned, you have chloride in solution. Looking into a good oxygen evolution catalyst as an anode might prevent this.

This is on the sixth question, 2.7A is a crazy high current for lab scale deposition. You will not be able to draw this amount of current without just making a bunch of hydrogen. You have to note that near your electrode surface, locally, the Gallium in solution will be depleted and more needs to come to the electrode by stirring and diffusion. So if you apply 2.7A, a small fraction will be Gallium and all the other current will be your electrolyte (forming hydrogen, or other stuff) Extracting all the Gallium from the solution by electrodeposition will be a very long process and it is beneficial to work in as high concentrated solution of Gallium as possible to not run into mass transport issues. Maybe it would be better to do the experiment in a potentiostatic way (apply a constant voltage).

Finally, I think it might be better to attempt to coat something with Ga electrochemically instead of extracting all of it. Bulk extraction is way easier with other methods. I have attempted Ga electrodeposition before, but from organic electrolytes. I can refer you to this paper, here you can have way higher current efficiencies as your electrolyte is not unstable in the potential range needed to deposition Gallium: https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2021/cp/d1cp01074c

Comment: THANK YOU! That article is a huge help, at least what I can understand. I also found the article that the chart you shared came from which is also helpful. For the 2.7amps, I just did my calculations based on only having one hour. I think I can get a spot in the lab to let it run for longer, but I was seeing what it would look like if I only had 1 hour.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HBMMgvqVY0&list=PLdW7n7SKdpHng1dl39_DfX4xovwVgk92Q&index=28&t=600s   <- this is what I am wanting to recreate. I didn't know if it would be possible to form crystals of Ga rather than a molten solution. I was looking at graphite because I'm not sure if I can convince a professor to give me a titanium and the only nickel I've seen in lab is a jar of nickel balls.